# How can I have a script executed just before the system goes to sleep?

Tags: linux, bash, systemd, dbus

How can I run a script in linux that can access kwallet, before the system goes to sleep?

Here I give more details:
I'm looking for a mechanism to execute a (user) script that runs before sleep/hibernate.

I initially tried a `systemd` (system) service, WantedBy `suspend.target`, `hibernate.target`, and `hybrid-sleep.target`.

The problem is that this service does not have access to `kwallet` since it is a system service (actually kwallet requires the user dbus context).

The next idea was to run a `systemd` user service. An user service has access to `kwallet`, but cannot be tied to  `suspend.target` or any of the others mentioned before.

I've been later advised to use a `logind` inhibitor hook. From what I read, this mechanism can be used by programs for inhibiting or delaying the transition to sleep mode, until some code is executed. Much like a lock. However, I do not find a tutorial or example that does this kind of hook with a simple bash script. I would appreciate if somebody, could point me to some article, or give an example of how could I do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I tired to make it more concise, but also tried to give the necessary details.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a plausible solution for this problem, as suggested in the answer to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149959/how-to-run-systemd-user-service-to-trigger-on-sleep-aka-suspend-hibernate).

The idea is to create systemd --user targets that are rised by listening to system events for sleep or lock, though dbus messages, and then use this targets to create another user service wanted by these targets. This has been implemented in [this repository](https://github.com/mogorman/systemd-lock-handler).

Initially, I was somewhat surprised by the absence of a systemd's native way to create user services wanted by system targets. But then, I realized my surprise was due to my ignorance of how systemd works. Systemd system services are executed by a single root process, while systemd user services run in separate user processes, and there is no straightforward way to link them together. With this understanding, the solution I found seams like a reasonable one.

I thank the people that read this post and gave a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to read this manual page:

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-sleep.8.html

Especially this section:

> Immediately before entering system suspend and/or hibernation
> systemd-suspend.service (and the other mentioned units,
> respectively) will run all executables in
> `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` and pass two arguments to them. The
> first argument will be "pre", the second either "suspend",
> "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep", or "suspend-then-hibernate" depending on
> the chosen action. An environment variable called
> "SYSTEMD_SLEEP_ACTION" will be set and contain the sleep action that
> is processing. This is primarily helpful for "suspend-then-hibernate"
> where the value of the variable will be "suspend", "hibernate", or
> "suspend-after-failed-hibernate" in cases where hibernation has
> failed. Immediately after leaving system suspend and/or hibernation
> the same executables are run, but the first argument is now "post".
>
> All executables in this directory are executed in parallel, and
> execution of the action is not continued until all executables have
> finished.

#### root can runs scripts as other users

#### `/tmp/test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
  echo "id: $(id)"
  echo "home: $HOME"
  echo "path: $PATH"
  echo "logname: $(logname)"
  echo "date: $(date)"
```

#### root runs `/tmp/test.sh` as user `u24`

```
sudo -u u24 /tmp/test.sh
```

##### output:

```
id: uid=1000(u24) gid=1000(u24) groups=1000(u24),4(adm),190(systemd-journal) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
home: /home/u24
path: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
logname: root
date: Mon Jun  6 08:28:08 UTC 2022
```

Comment: Hello @dudi-boy. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I've learned another thing I did not know it was possible to do with systemd. It is very cool. Unfortunately, it does not  solve the problem I have, since the hook scripts are still executed as root and get no access to the DBUS context of the user. I get the error:
`Environment variable DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is unset`
This is my script:
`#!/bin/bash

#Disconnect from protonvpn before sleep
echo "$1, $2" >> /home/user/log.log
[[ "$1" == "pre" ]] && protonvpn-cli d >> /home/user/log.log || echo "Not run" >> /home/user/log.log
`

Comment: `the hook scripts are still executed as root and get no access to the DBUS context` you can use `sudo -iu <your-user> <your-script>`. try with `-i` and without `-i`

Comment: Add sample script in the answer above. How root can run scripts as other user.

Comment: Oh that is very neat! I will surely try this. It did not think in using sudo to run my command as another (less privileged user). I could use this in a systemd system service, as I wanted to do at first. Is there a reason to prefer a system-sleep hook to a system service wanted by the suspend.target?

Comment: service that depends or wants `suspend.target` cannot run after suspends completed since the system is suspended. The best option is to use hook scripts or implement `Inhibitor interface` in your suspended application.

Comment: I suggest making a service (myService) that is WantedBy=suspend.target, and not the other way around. In my understanding, the system would not go to sleep after myService has completed. Am I wrong?

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I still have the same problem of not having access to the DBUS session and the user credentials stored in kwallet, Neither, `sudo -u  user -i`, `sudo -user`, nor `su -l user` do the trick,  In fact, I want to run protonvpn-cli, which needs to access kwallet. I will make another post with a question focused around dbus. Most suggestions I've found about accessing a user dbus session, do not work for my case. When solved, I will likely use the hooks you showed to me. Thanks again, for taking the time.